# grab non consecutive frame from IP camera

Tags: c, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm working on project where I need to retrieve frame from IP camera every second (or two) and process it some way.
After initialization of capture with

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile(ipSource);
```

I'm getting the frames from a loop where I introduce one (or two) second(s) delay -

```
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

Problem - I only get consecutive frames (from buffer I suppose), not the frame in moment I try to get it.
What should I do to get frame in the moment I want to?

Answer (score 0):

`cvQueryFrame` actually calls `cvGrabFrame()` and then `cvRetrieveFrame()`. The first function retrieves the image from the camera and stores it internally. The second frame actually decompresses it and return the IPLImage to you. You could manually call it and put your processor heavy code between them.

Other option (quick and dirty) is to run a different thread which will grab the frames continuously. You could then get the latest frame easily.

Hope that helps..